# Display UILocalNotification on app force quit

Tags: ios, uilocalnotification

`- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application` does not come for rescue as it gets called by the OS when the app is about to be killed due to low memory conditions. [Lookout app](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/lookout-backup-security-missing/id434893913?mt=8) displays Local notification when the app is force quit after going to the background mode or even double tap home button and kill the App. Does any one have a solution to find the Appp Force quit event.

Comment: Actually if you forec quite the app "- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(UIApplication *)application" method will fire. 

do you programmatically quite you app within the app?